# main function of the code is to get id's and name the to save them to a txt file,search , sort the data so far iam done with everything how do i sort

Tags: c++, class, sorting, structure

i have a  c++ project to get user input,like patient id,name,email,and diagnostics then i have to save them in a text file and sort them what would be the best data type for the project struct or classes and if so why is it?I've already got user input but i have a problem sorting the records in alphabetical order.

for example

INPUT

```
name:man
surname:bull
patient id:1234
name:cow
patientid:1234
surname:arrow
```

SORTED WORDS

```
name:cow
patientid:1234
surname:arrow
name:man
surname:bull
patient id:1234
```

Comment: In C++, the keywords `struct` and `class` both define a type that the language calls a "class".  You may use either.  There is not much we can say about your sorting "problem" without knowing what the problem is and the code that is failing for you.

Comment: In what sense are those words sorted?

Comment: ok thanks for but what do i need to do in order to sort that data

Comment: Dave Newton in alphabetical order

Comment: _"what do i need to do in order to sort that data"_  [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is a common solution for sorting data.

Comment: Create a `struct` or `class` with the fields.  Define an `operator<` method for your `class` or `struct`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `operator<` method for your class:

```
class Record
{
    std::string  m_name;
    std::string  m_surname;
    unsigned int m_patient_id;
  public:  
    // Default ordering method.
    bool operator<(const Record& r)
    {
        if (m_name == r.m_name)
        {
            if (m_surname == r.m_surname)
            {
                return m_patient_id < r.m_patient_id;
            }
            return m_surname < r.m_surname;
        }
        return m_name < r.m_name;
    }
};
```

The overloaded `operator<` method allows you to use functions that order or compare for sorting, such as `std::sort`.

If you are writing your own sort function, use the expression `if (a < b)` for comparing, don't access the individual fields.  Better is to use a comparison function, but that is another topic.